# SSRS - Send an email based on the query

Tags: sql-server, powershell, reporting-services, power-automate

I have a query that produces results of a user's email address and their computer depending on how long they have not turned their computer on. IE if the user has not turned their computer on in 20+ days the query will produce:

host_name   //user_name //user_email    //Time Stamp    //Time  //Todays-Date   //DateDiff

My question is based on the user's email I would like to send an email or even better a teams message to the user to get their computer(usually a laptop) onto the internet so that it will be updated via config manager.

I was thinking SSRS, power automate, or a powershell script but I am at a loss as to where to begin.

Comment: Results for the query only show if the computer has not been seen for 20 days or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you decide to go with ssrs. I would split the string to extract user's email in sql code and do data driven subscription with email as destination. The email returned from query would be passed to To variable.

Comment: Thank you! I made a query and was able to send emails to users based on the report! -- For everyone else you would need to set the subscription to a variable.

Comment: If the answer was useful for for you don't be afraid to accept the answer ;) anyway glad you solved that out